# Windows Phone 7.5 - AutoCompleteBox Populating event

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I develop application for WP7.5. This app uses AutocompletexeBox from Silverlight Toolkit. I created custom logic for it. But my problem is, that Populating event is raised twice, not only once.

Here is my code:

```
void OnPopulating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var populateAsyncCommand = PopulateAsyncCommand;

        if (populateAsyncCommand != null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            populateAsyncCommand.Execute(new PopulateAsyncArgs{ CompleteAction = AssociatedObject.PopulateComplete, FilterParameter = e.Parameter});
        }
    }
```

In this event I execute command, which is binded in View. Problem is, that this event isn't raised only once and I can't explain it, why.

Thanks for advice.